# Is there a way to measure the branch production rate of a system in the many worlds interpretation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations

Is there a way to measure the branch production rate of a system in the many worlds interpretation? My understanding is that chaotic systems with sensitive dependence on initial conditions is likely to create more branches.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't your fault, but I sure wish the many worlds people used better language to describe what they are actually saying.

Your question essentially assumes that at time $t$ there are $N(t)$ worlds, and you want to know $dN/dt$, which sounds like it should be a reasonable question.

But $N(t)$ is not well-defined in the many-worlds interpretation, because "the world splits into multiple branches" is not really a good way to describe what the many-worlds interpretation says.

There is *one* wavefunction, which describes the state of the entire Universe.

If we think of *you* as a detector, then one thing we can ask is what is the probability distribution for *you* to detect some signal in your environment (eg: do you *see* an alive cat or dead cat, or does the subsystem consisting of you + the cat involve an alive cat or a dead cat). If we look at the subspace of all degrees of freedom that make you up, then because of [decoherence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_decoherence) there is set of possibilities for what you observe. You experience one of those possible states. As "stuff happens," the set of possible states of you changes in a complicated way. It's complicated because to calculate the set of possible states you could be in, you have to "trace over" all the possible values of the degrees of freedom you interacts with (every electron in every air molecule that could bump into you, for example), and there are a lot of those. No one can actually do that calculation, so no one can give you a quantitative answer.

The different set of states that you can be in (or, any given subsystem of the whole Universe can be in), after tracing out other degrees of freedom, is what I *think* the many-worlds folks mean by a "branch" of the wave function. In particular, note that this is not actually a property of the Universe or of the wave function, but of trying to account for observations you make (or of the behavior of a given subsystem).